# insert image into text buffer

Tags: emacs, insert-image

If I place

```
(insert-image (create-image "/tmp/test.png"))
```

in a buffer, place the cursor after the last parenthesis and evaluate it with `C-x C-e`, then the image `/tmp/test.png` is displayed in the buffer:

[image]

Pretty neat. But,

1. I had to put the final parenthesis on a separate line, so the image
   is close to the left-hand side of the buffer. Is there a way to hide
   the `(insert-image ...)` text altogether?
2. The text file contains the `(insert-image ...)` text only, not the
   image. I'm happy with that, but is there a way to tell emacs to
   automatically replace all the `(insert-image ...)` expressions by
   their corresponding images (after the file is opened) without me having to type `C-x C-e` after
   each one?

Comment: insert-image actually doesn't insert any image into the buffer to save it on to the disk instead its just visual representation. you didn't mention the purpose. In org-mode you can link pictures in the buffer and display them if you want, and export them. is that what you are looking for.?

Comment: I'm lookimg for true inline images - where the image data exists in the emacs buffer, probably uuencoded, rather than a pointer to a file containing the image-data.  It's a pain to manage separate files.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Take a look at [`iimage-mode`](https://github.com/typester/emacs/blob/master/lisp/iimage.el), the inline image minor mode.  It's included since Emacs-23, IIRC.

<kbd>M-x</kbd>`iimage-mode`

Comment: +1: I did not know of this mode, but this is definitely the way to go: standard and not overfeatured.

Comment: Here's a Wayback Machine link to the original link: https://web.archive.org/web/20120424055608/http://www.netlaputa.ne.jp/~kose/Emacs/iimage.html

Answer (score 34):

Depending on exactly what you want to achieve, you might try one the the following ideas:

**1.** use `org-mode` as your buffer's major mode. You then have access to all the power of `org-mode` formatting, which includes linking to image files and displaying them:

```
an image without description
[[file:/tmp/image.png]]

an image with description
[[file:/tmp/image.png][my description]]
```

then you can call `org-toggle-inline-images` (<kbd>C-c C-x C-v</kbd>) to display images in the buffer (without a prefix argument, it will display only images without description; if you give a prefix argument, it will display all images)

**2.** write your own elisp code to insert images where you want them, and put it in an `eval` local pseudo-variable so that it is called when opening the file. For example:

```
foo
<HERE>
bar

# Local Variables:
#   eval: (progn (beginning-of-buffer)(search-forward "<HERE>")(insert-image (create-image "/tmp/image.png")))
# End:
```

You can of course wrap the elisp code into a neat function and simply call it from the `eval` local variable (which is cleaner, but forces you to have the function definition somewhere else, away from your file)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the text (actually lisp code) in the buffer, don't type it into the buffer in the first place. Try `M-x eval-expression` and enter your lisp code after the Eval prompt:

```
(insert-image (create-image "/tmp/test.png"))
```

Then the image is inserted at point in the buffer. You can define a function like this:

```
(defun my-insert-image () (interactive) (insert-image (create-image "/tmp/test.png")))
```

Either type `M-x eval-expression` and the above defun or type it into a buffer and `C-x C-e` after it. Then you can insert the image using `M-x my-insert-image`.

Comment: Probably better to use `(defun my-insert-image (image-file) (interactive "fImage File: ") (insert-image (create-image image-file)))`.

Comment: Or as the manual says (http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Images.html)      

(defimage test-image
        ((:type xpm :file "~/test1.xpm")
         (:type xbm :file "~/test1.xbm")))

(insert-image test-image)