# Pseudo-WYSIWYG Emacs

Tags: emacs, documentation

With just the few lines in a file `file.adoc`

```
////
-*-iimage-mode-*-
////

.A PNG smiley
image::smiley.png[]
```

I can generate HTML using `asciidoctor` and MS-word `.doc` using `pandoc`.
This toolchain doesn't handle SVG, and so it's not perfect, but it works well, and
it's free.

*file.html*

[image: smiley in a rendered HTML file]

There is a snag though:

I'd like [`iimage-mode`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15763705/704972) to be enabled when I load `file.adoc`. My attempt (the first three lines in the source above) doesn't work. Can you think of a way that will?

*.emacs*

```
(set-foreground-color "white")
(set-background-color "black")

(require 'adoc-mode)
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.adoc\\'" . adoc-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```

**Comments**

I am writing these comments here to be able to typeset.

1. Asciidoctor
   (I'm using to the superior implementation of the asciidoc syntax written in [Ruby](http://asciidoctor.org/)) does have (now?) [line comments](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/asciidoc-syntax-quick-reference/#comments) in addition to block comments.
2. Using

   // -*- mode: iimage -*-

on the first line works (thanks, Nick). But it replaces the adoc major mode (thanks, phils).

3. Adding at the bottom of the file:

`//// Local Variables:`

`eval: (iimage-mode 1)`

`End:`

`////`

switches to minor mode iimage while the major mode remains adoc.

4. phils's suggestion to use `my-adoc-mode-hook` works well.

I'm [forking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43098176/704972) the second part to a separate question. This discussion is already long enough for one question.

**Update**

Using asciidoctor + pandoc may produce a `.doc` file that is handled correctly with a recent version of MS-Word. Comments welcome. MS-Word 2011 on OS X opens the resulting `.doc` file fine, but shows an error message in the place of SVG images.

If this works, it will (finally) be a way to send a `.doc` file to all those people who insist on them, while editing in an environment as flexible as Emacs.

Comment: In general, Emacs does not create/depict lines through PNG images that are displayed in `image-mode`.  Does this happen with `emacs -q`?  I.e., just open the PNG in a buffer all by itself with zero user configuration -- it should default to `image-mode`.

Comment: `adoc-mode` isn't standard, so tell us where it came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nick's answer is mostly correct, but `iimage-mode` is a *minor* mode, and using `mode:...` in local variables is (nowadays) intended for *major* modes only. Using it to enable minor modes is deprecated (even if it still works in some situations<sup>1</sup>).

Instead use `eval:...` to call the minor mode function like so<sup>2</sup>:

```el
//// -*- eval: (iimage-mode 1); -*-
```

or

```el
//// Local Variables:
//// eval: (iimage-mode 1)
//// End:
```

Note also that `-*- iimage -*-` is equivalent to `-*- mode: iimage -*-`, and that for both forms Emacs appends a `-mode` suffix to get the *actual* mode name.

Hence `-*-iimage-mode-*-` is asking to use `iimage-mode-mode` -- and in fact Emacs should have produced a message "Ignoring unknown mode `iimage-mode-mode'".

Finally, if you want `iimage-mode` enabled for *all* `adoc-mode` files, then you can use a mode hook in your init file instead of using file-local variables:

```el
(add-hook 'adoc-mode-hook 'my-adoc-mode-hook)

(defun my-adoc-mode-hook ()
  "Custom `adoc-mode' behaviours."
  (iimage-mode 1))
```

<sup>1</sup> In this case, if you *had* used `-*-iimage-*-` or `-*-mode: iimage-*-` as the only local variable mode spec, Emacs would treat it as a major mode, and your intended `adoc-mode` major mode would not be used.

<sup>2</sup> I'm following Nick's answer in assuming that `////` is the correct line-comment prefix, but the question makes it look more like a block comment syntax, so I don't know if it's correct.

Comment: Thanks (again) for setting me right. The minor mode warning is right there on the page that I linked to and I'm sure I have seen it before, but I forgot all about it.

Answer (score 2):

1. I tried with a JPG that I had lying around and I don't get any artifacts at all.
2. The spec is `-*- mode: iimage -*-` and it's got to be on the first line of the file (it can be on the second if the first line specifies an interpreter, e.g. #! /bin bash).

If that does not work for you, you can use a file variable at the *end* of the file:

```
//// Local Variables:
//// mode: iimage
//// End:
```

See [File Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables).

EDIT: See @phils's answer for a more correct description of how to handle minor modes.