# Strikethrough in Emacs image mode

Tags: emacs, asciidoctor

With a `.emacs` [loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43077371/a-poor-mans-image-and-text-editor) `iimage-mode` and [adoc-mode](https://github.com/sensorflo/adoc-mode):

```
;; Don't glare 200W in my eyes all day:
(set-foreground-color "white")
(set-background-color "black")

;; Use adoc as major mode for any file with the extension .adoc.
(require 'adoc-mode)
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.adoc\\'" . adoc-mode) auto-mode-alist))

;; Use iimage-mode as minor mode whenever we're in adoc-mode.
(add-hook 'adoc-mode-hook 'my-adoc-mode-hook)
(defun my-adoc-mode-hook ()
  "Custom `adoc-mode' behaviours."
  (iimage-mode 1))
```

if I convert the file `file.adoc`

```
.A PNG smiley
image::smiley.png[]
```

to HTML using [Asciidoctor](http://asciidoctor.org/)

```
asciidoctor file.adoc
```

I get the nicely formatted HTML file

[image: easy HTML]

but Emacs shows a distracting strikethrough

[image: strikethrough]

How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're running into adoc's markup fontification for internal references. I was able to make that line go away by removing the underlining from `markup-internal-reference-face`. Something like this added to your `.emacs` might fix it:

```
(custom-set-faces
 '(markup-internal-reference-face ((t (:inherit markup-meta-face)))))
```